# Using the washer method find the volume of the solid generated by the enclosed region

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid generated when the region enclosed by $y=e^x$ and $y=\ln x$ between $x=1/2$ and $x=1$ is revolved about the line $x=-4$.

I've tried setting it up using the standard of the outer radius subtracted by the inner radius but I'm not sure if it's set right because the region is enclosed by intersections.

$$\pi \int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1\:\left(e^x-\left(-4\right)\right)^2-\left(\ln\left(x\right)-\left(-4\right)\right)^2,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

The washer method for revolving about the y axis is:

Consider x inside the region 1/2 and 1 and a infinitesimal width dx the washer dA is (neglecting $(dx)^2$)

$$dA = \pi((4 + x + dx)^2 - (4 + x)^2)dx = 2\pi (4 + x)dx$$
Hence the volume is

$$V = 2\pi\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(e^x - ln x)(4 + x)dx$$
$$ = 2\pi\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(4e^x + xe^x - 4ln x - xln x)dx$$
$$= 2\pi(4e - \frac{7}{2}\sqrt{e} + \frac{35}{16} - \frac{17}{8}ln 2)$$
$$= 36.55$$